# Keycode / encoding problem for cyrrilic letters in key send operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, ascii, keycode

I am facing a very rare problem, that I couldn't solve myself even after hours of googling it.

I use `node-key-sender` (but the problem is similar for other look-a-like modules, such as `robots.js`) for keyboard emittance (Keyboard button send operations)

The following function works fine when I am using any English word:

```
const ks = require('node-key-sender');

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async function query (query = 'Bread') {
    try {
        query = query.toLowerCase()
        await sleep(1000)
        ks.sendText(query); //prints bread in real time after 1 second delay
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})();
```

But when I am trying to use it for any Cyrillic word, it does nothing, because it doesn't contain any «alphabet map», but If I add it, it works fine, but...

```
const ks = require('node-key-sender');

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const RuMap = {
    "й": 'q', "ц": 'w', "у": 'e', "к": 'r', "е": 't', "н": 'y', "г": 'u', "ш": 'i', "щ": 'o', "з": 'p', "х": 'shift-@55', "ъ": 'close_bracket',
    "ф": 'a', "ы": 's', "в": 'd', "а": 'f', "п": 'g', "р": 'h', "о": 'j', "л": 'k', "д": 'l', "ж": ';', "э": "'",
    "я": 'z', "ч": 'x', "с": 'c', "м": 'v', "и": 'b', "т": 'n', "ь": 'm', "б": '', "ю": 'slash',
};

(async function query (query = 'Хлеб') {
    try {
        query = query.toLowerCase()
        ks.aggregateKeyboardLayout(RuMap);
        await sleep(1000)
        ks.sendText(query); //prints only 'л' and 'е'
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})();
```

The problem is, that if I want to print any non-English word, I should change **language keyboard** in my OS, and run this function, so the Cyrillic letters have been converted to the English counterparts, like `Q => Й`, according to language layout map:
[image]

Example:

> So, if I want to print the word `ЙЦУКЕН` I should convert every letter for `QWERTY`, and machine prints emit the following key, and prints `ЙЦУКЕН`, because my language layout is Cyrillic right now in the OS.

[image]

And it works fine, until I don't face the cyrrilic `Х => [` problem. Open bracket has [KeyCode `@219`](https://keycode.info/) or [`VK_OPEN_BRACKET` (in Java KeyEvent)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html). But even if I add to layout `{ "х": '@219' }` or `{ "х": 'open_bracket' }` it still doesn't work.

As I figure it out, KeySend somehow changes or it does relevant with the `non-ASCI` symbols problem.

So in Cyrillic layout, `shift+@55` KeyCode is relevant to `?`, but in the English layout `?` doesn't have keyCode `@55` so, how to find KeyCodes for Cyrillic layout and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode Subtrange with Character Map helps me out after 4 hours of coding:

[image]

`"х": '@18-@96-@98-@100-@101'` which equals to `Alt+0245` for all characters, which doesn't have KeyCodes in active OS layout.